# gephi error when parsing datetime

Tags: xml, datetime, gephi

I'm trying to display a dynamic .gexf file in Gephi, where the datetime information is in the following format: `2001-12-07 10:06:42`

Unfortunately, I keep getting the error `The time interval for node XY could not be parsed. Use xsd:date, xsd:dateTime or Double formatting.`

I have also added the following info to the .gexf file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gexf version="1.2" xmlns="http://www.gexf.net/1.2draft" xmlns:viz="http://www.gexf.net/1.2draft/viz" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <graph defaultedgetype="directed" mode="dynamic" timeformat="datetime">
    <attributes class="node" mode="dynamic">
      <attribute id="0" title="duration" type="string"/>
      <attribute id="1" title="end" type="string"/>
    </attributes>
    <nodes> (...)
```

But still no success with parsing datetime. Any help with this would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should anyone face this issue in future, I managed to solve it by putting a `T` between the date and time information, e.g.:

`2001-12-07 10:06:42`  changed to   `2001-12-07T10:06:42`

(Sidenote: both datetime informations are strings)

Comment: Huge help! You should accept your own answer because that worked for me - thank you!!!

Comment: Glad it helped you! :)